# Is there standard way in grails to manage plurals in international strings from property files?

Tags: grails, internationalization

Using the plugin for international, is there a "proper" way to pluralize words dynamically, or select the plural version of a property?

Comment: Just an FYI about this: not all languages have [just two quantity identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural#Other_languages), so this may be a lot harder than you think at first, depending on your natural language requirements.

Answer (score 23):

You can use an embedded `ChoiceFormat` in the i18n message. Using an example from [the `java.text.MessageFormat` Javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) you could define something like:

```
numfiles.message = "There {0,choice,0#are no files|1#is one file|1<are {0,number,integer} files}."
```

Then in your GSP:

```
<g:message code="numfiles.message" args="[numfiles]"/>
```

Where `numfiles` is an integer value.

Answer (score 2):

As @overzealous had noticed in comments, not all languages have the same simple plural rules as English language has. English has just two forms: `one` (quantity is 1, e.g. 1 car, 1 hour) and `other` (quantity is more than 1, e.g. 3 cars, 11 hours). In this case pluralization can be handled pretty simple in Grails using `ChoiseFormat`. However, some languages have more than two forms, for example Polish has 4 forms: `one` (e.g. 1 auto), `few` (e.g. 2 auta), `many` (e.g. 6 aut) and `other`. [Here is a link](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html) to the table describing plural rules for all languages.

I've also wrote [a plugin for Grails](http://grails.org/plugin/icu) which adds rich pluralization abilities using table above. Using it you can just write in `messages.properties`

```
msgcode={0} {0, plural, one{auto}few{auta}many{aut}other{aut}}
```

and then use it:

```
<g:message code="msgcode" args="[3]"/>
```

will print `3 auta`.